# Lost access to files after Windows reinstall

Tags: windows-10

So I had to reinstall my OS (Windows 10) and now I don't have access to most of my files.

I already tried both icacls and takeown using Cmd but for some of the files the access is denied.

To add to this, I've found that while I'm able to move in between folders I can't execute them (even if they're texts or imagines) but if I try and do it individually I can access the files.

Is there any way I can automate this process?

**EDIT:**
My PC has 2 hard drives. The one where Windows is installed is working just fine and everything is accessible. The other one still has it's permissions assigned to the old user (whose name is now displayed has S-1-5--bunchOfNumbers). If I manually change the ownership of the file (by right-clicking and going to it's properties) I can make it work.

I already changed the ownership to this drive and tried both takeown and icacls and a lot of the files are already usable but some others the permission can't be changed in the cmd (it says it's access is denied). Thing is if I were to do it manually for every file in this hard drive, I'd be stuck doing it for a long long time. So I'm not sure what's the best course of action.

Also, if I go through each file I can see I have ownership of the files but in the permissions tab I only see 2 users (SYSTEM and the old one)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you access your files using the Command Prompt in WinRE? Also, what method did you use to reinstall Windows? Did you use the Media Creation Tool, Reset the PC Keeping Filed, Refresh the PC, use a Repair Disk?

Comment: I just got it back from the store so I don't really know. Regarding your question, everything works fine, it's just the files permissions/control is given to the old user so I can't access them. But if manually remove the permissions from that user and give it to the new ones, everything works

Comment: See https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2020/02/15/microsoft-acknowledges-serious-windows-10-update-bug-that-removes-your-files-and-profile/#6ab03ca65f32